# Can I get multiple complete binary trees for a given array by different methods?

Tags: java, heap, cbt

Here I build the heap following two methods:

[image: hand solution]

Can I get multiple complete binary trees for a given array?

- Method 1 - Insertion;
- Method 2 - Sub trees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get different complete binary trees as heaps for the same data, depending of the method you use to build the heap.

Note that the first (insertion) method [Williams’ method] is less efficient than the second [Floyd’s method], but they both produce a correct heap, even though they are not equal. See [Wikipedia: building a heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap)

Comment: Thanks This was a deadly doubt for me .